# How to pass JSON Data to KendoUI Grid

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-grid

today i'm trying to implement a kendo gridview to my website, actually i'm using a webservice that give me a JSON Result.
This is the result:

```
[{"IdComponente":"8","NoParte":"12","Descripcion":"Componente A","CostoUnitario":"0.12"},{"IdComponente":"9","NoParte":"123","Descripcion":"Componente B","CostoUnitario":"0.23"},{"IdComponente":"10","NoParte":"1234","Descripcion":"Componente C","CostoUnitario":"0.54"},{"IdComponente":"11","NoParte":"12345","Descripcion":"Componente D","CostoUnitario":"0.90"},{"IdComponente":"12","NoParte":"123456","Descripcion":"Componente E","CostoUnitario":"1.25"},{"IdComponente":"13","NoParte":"1234567","Descripcion":"Componente F","CostoUnitario":"0.12"},{"IdComponente":"14","NoParte":"12345678","Descripcion":"Componente G","CostoUnitario":"0.12"},{"IdComponente":"16","NoParte":"123456789","Descripcion":"Componente H","CostoUnitario":"0.98"}]
```

And i'm using this script, the problem is that i don't get any error in the console, but it doesn't show me the information in the grid. 
So, i don't know why, because the json result its okay..

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WSComponentes.asmx/obtenerComponentes",
            data: '',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json", // dataType is json format
            success: function OnSuccess(response) {
                cargarGrid(response);
            },
            error: function onError(error) {
                console.log(error.d);
            },
        });
    });

    function cargarGrid(datos) {
        console.log(datos);
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                dataType: 'json',
                data: datos,
                schema: {
                    data: "d",
                    type: "json",
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            IdComponente: { editable: false, type: "string" },
                            NoParte: { editable: false, type: "string" },
                            Descripcion: { editable: false, type: "string" },
                            CostoUnitario: { editable: false, type: "string" }
                        }
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 10
            },
            height: 550,
            groupable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: true,
                buttonCount: 5
            },
            columns: [{
                field: "IdComponente",
                title: "IdComponente",
            }, {
                field: "NoParte",
                title: "NoParte"
            }, {
                field: "Descripcion",
                title: "Descripcion"
            }, {
                field: "CostoUnitario",
                title: "CostoUnitario",
            }
            ]
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not far away with what you have.. You need to declare a [`kendo.data.DataSource`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource):

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    dataType: 'json',
    data: datos,
    schema: {                                            
      model: {
        fields: {
          IdComponente: { editable: false, type: "string" },
          NoParte: { editable: false, type: "string" },
          Descripcion: { editable: false, type: "string" },
          CostoUnitario: { editable: false, type: "string" }
        }
      }
    },
    pageSize: 10
});
```

Which is then used in your grid declaration like so:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource, ....
```

Here is a [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/UcofE/6) to demonstrate implementation changes required.